# Fast method call scheduling in Python

Tags: python, linux, multithreading, timer, scheduling

For some part of my project I need a process-local scheduling system that will allow me to delay method execution on few seconds. I have thousands of “clients” of this system, so using `threading.Timer` for each delay is a bad idea because I will quickly reach OS thread limit. I've [implemented](http://pastebin.com/tUeaWkBg) a system that use only one thread for timing control.

The main idea is to keep sorted task (time + func + args + kwargs) queue and to use single `threading.Timer` to schedule/cancel executions of the head of this queue. This scheme works, but I'm not happy with performance. ~2000 clients that schedule dummy tasks every ~10 seconds cause the process to take 40% of CPU time. Looking at profiler output I see that all time is spent on new `threading.Timer`s construction, its start and particularly on new threads creation.

I believe there is a better way. Now I think about rewriting the `LightTimer` so that there will be one execution thread controllable by `threading.Event` and several timing threads that will `set()` the event. For example:

- I schedule a task to call in 10 secs. The task is added to a queue. Timing thread #1 starts `time.sleep(10)` before `event.set()`
- Then I schedule a task to call in 11 secs. The task is added to the queue. Nothing happens with timing thread, it will notice new task after wake up.
- Then I schedule a task to call in 5 secs. The task is prepended to the queue. Timing thread #2 starts `time.sleep(5)` because #1 sleeps already for a longer interval.

I hope you've caught the idea. What do you think about this way? Is there a better way? Maybe I can utilize some linux system features to make optimal solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative implementation you could use is to use the `time.time()` method to calculate the absolute time each queued function should be executed. Place this time and your function-to-be-called in an object wrapper that overrides the comparison operator using the execution time to determine order. Then use the `heapq` module to maintain a min-heap. This will provide you with an efficient datastructure where element 0 of the heap is always your next event.

One way to implement the actual calls would be to use a separate thread to execute the callbacks. The heap will need to be protected with a mutex and you can use a condition variable to implement the scheduling. In an infinite loop, just lookup the next time to execute a function (element 0 of the heap) and use the condition variable's `wait()` method with the timeout set to the next execution time. Your heap insertion method could then use the condition variable's `notify()` method to wake the scheduling thread early if the newly inserted function should occur prior to the earliest one already in the heap.

Comment: Hm… very interesting, thanks! Especially I've never looked at `heapq` and didn't thought about using `threading.Condition` for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at the [sched](http://docs.python.org/library/sched.html?highlight=sched#module-sched) module in the Python standard library?  Running the scheduler on a dedicated thread (and having all the scheduled actions be "put a bound method and its args on a queue" from which threads in a pool peel and execute it -- much as I wrote in the Nutshell chapter on threads, except that in that case there was no scheduling) should do what you want.

Comment: And how to deal with a statement from the docs *“the scheduler  class has limitations with respect to thread-safety, inability to insert a new task before the one currently pending in a running scheduler”*? Does it mean I *can* insert a new task before one currently pending but from the same thread or do I have to spawn multiple threads running sched?

Comment: @nailxx, it does require some care -- that warning relates to "naive" uses, such as, using the "normal" delayfunc (just time.sleep) or executing a scheduler's method from multiple threads.  With a delayfunc that does a Queue.get with timeout on a dedicated queue (so wakes up as soon as anything is pushed on the queue... and pulls it and performs scheduling method calls if needed) -- and pushing from other threads to that dedicated Queue in lieu of calling scheduler methods from them -- I have successfully used a single scheduler instance in a similar multi-threaded scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You are unlikely to reach the OS thread limit with "a few thousand clients"; you may consume a lot of unnecessary memory with the stacks for all those threads though.

Have a look at what twisted does, it allows a process to multiplex a lot of events (including timers) in a way which has proven to work quite well with large numbers of events.

You can also combine event-driven and multi-process models, by running several processes per machine and doing event-driven logic in each one - say one process can handle 2,000 clients, you can still run 30x processes (provided there is sufficient overall resource) and gain better throughput, especially on modern multi-core hardware.

Comment: *You are unlikely to reach the OS thread limit* — I actually did it :)

Comment: I expect you exhausted address space with all those stacks. Linux default stack size is typically 1M (or similar), so it only takes a couple of thousand threads to use up A/S in a 32-bit process. The OS has a much higher limit.